# How do I get the coordinates of the current view port in an Excel Sheet?

Tags: charts, excel, viewport, vba

I need to place a chart in the center of an Excel Worksheet, right where the user is currently viewing.
Apparently 0 is the very beginning on the X axis of the sheet's coordinate system, and the X increases as we move to the right. The user might be viewing columns J to Z for example, and I need the coordinates of where in the sheet the user is viewing, so I can place the chart right in front of him.

How do I get the coordinates of the "view port" of a sheet relative to the sheet's coordinate system?
Is there any other, simpler methods to just put the chart there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

you could try something like

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox Application.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.VisibleRange.AddressLocal
End Sub
```

In my case it opens the msgbox with content `$A$271:$X$312`
I hope this helped you out.

EDIT:

Ok, tried to figure it out with X Y coordinates and got to the following:

```
Sub TestPixel()
    With Range(ActiveWindow.ActivePane.VisibleRange.AddressLocal)
        Debug.Print .Left, .Top
        Debug.Print .Left + .Width, .Top + .Height
    End With
End Sub
```

Prints out the top left x/y coordinate and the bottom right x/y coordinate

EDIT no2.:

Just had a few minutes and completed your task with my testworkbook.
Here's the makro:

```
Sub PositionDiagramm()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    Dim height As Integer
    Dim width As Integer

    With Range(ActiveWindow.ActivePane.VisibleRange.AddressLocal)
        x = .Left
        y = .Top
        width = .Width
        height = .Height
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm 1")
    .Top = y + ((height - .Height) / 2)
    .Left = x + ((width - .Width) / 2)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Got me 1 step closer, thanks. But I need the coordinates - in pixels - of the visible range, as the chart requires screen coordinates. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: nice one. Some comments on your code. First, you should use `Dim x as Integer, y as Integer` and so on. It doesn't work the way you've written it. Second, you should write in english your vars instead of german, this will be easier to read for any non-german-speaking person

Comment: Thank you for the comment on the Dim statement. I just read that the variables without `as Type` are declared as Variants. Didn't know that. For the variable names: as this is an english QA site i agree on that.